# Programmatically Gift Badge in Community Site

Tags: 2013, community-site

Does anyone know if it is possible to programmatically gift badges to users in SharePoint 2013 community sites?

For example I would like to add an event receiver so that whenever anyone is added to the "moderators" group they are giving a badge "moderator".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, since members are stored in a regular list (named `Community Members`) in Community site, you could perform CRUD operations using any API (SSOM, CSOM, REST, SOAP)

### Example

How to set Gifted Badge to a Member via CSOM (JavaScript)

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Community Members');
listItem = list.getItemById(1); //get member item
listItem.set_item('GiftedBadgeLookup', 1); //set Gifted Badge = Expert (Lookup Id = 1)
listItem.update();
context.load(listItem);
context.executeQueryAsync(
   function(){
       console.log('Gifted Badge has been set to: ' + listItem.get_item('GiftedBadgeLookup').get_lookupValue());    
   }, 
   function(sender,args)
   {
      console.log(args.get_message());     
   }
);
```